# Generating Pivot table with If case

Tags: vba, excel

I am having an sheet BW. and another sheet Man.

I am generating the pivot table with the data of "BW".

I am generating the pivot table with row field as Column "S" . I would like to have an condition. If the column "Z" contains "Ontime" then I just need the count for the column "T"  in my pivot table. if it is "" then I don't want the count of "T".

IS it possible I can do in this way ?

Can anyone help

I have tried the below code.

```
Sub AutoPivot5()
Dim ws5 As Worksheet
Dim pc5 As PivotCache
Dim pt5 As PivotTable
Dim ct5 As Integer
Set ws5 = Sheets("Man")
Set pc5 = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, "'BW'!R4C16:R1048576C21")
Set pt5 = pc5.CreatePivotTable(ws5.Range("A3"))
pt5.AddDataField pt5.PivotFields("OVERDUE"), "Sum of OVERDUE", xlSum
With pt5
With .PivotFields("Location")
.Orientation = xlRowField
.Position = 1
.AutoSort xlDescending, "Sum of OVERDUE"
pt5.TableRange2.Offset(0, 1).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
End With
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: can anyone help with this ?

Comment: can you share a screen shot of your sheet's data, which is used for the Pivot Table ?

Comment: A sample data would do  ?

Comment: yes it would do

Comment: @ShaiRado I could not produce an sample data. but I can explain you if you have queries

Comment: @ShaiRado I can not give yu the real data also